# Syntax error: SYN0001 despite it working on the Kusto query editor online

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm building queries in Python and executing them on my Kusto clusters using Kusto client's  `execute_query` method.

I've been hit by the following error: `azure.kusto.data.exceptions.KustoApiError: Request is invalid and cannot be processed: Syntax error: SYN0001: I could not parse that, sorry. [line:position=0:0]`.

However, when debugging, I've taken the query as it is, and ran it on my clusters thru the Kusto platform on Azure.

The query is similar to the following:

```
StormEvents
| where ingestion_time() > ago(1h)
| summarize
    count_matching_regex_State=countif(State matches regex "[A-Z]*"),
    count_not_empty_State=countif(isnotempty(State))
| summarize
    Matching_State=sum(count_matching_regex_State),
    NotEmpty_State=sum(count_not_empty_State)
| project
    ratio_State=todouble(Matching_State) / todouble(Matching_State + NotEmpty_State)
| project
    ratio_State=iff(isnan(ratio_State), 0.0, round(ratio_State, 3))
```

Queries are built in Python using string interpolations and such:

```py
## modules.py
def match_regex_query(fields: list, regex_patterns: list, kusto_client):
        def match_regex_statements(field, regex_patterns):
            return " or ".join(list(map(lambda pattern: f"{field} matches regex \"{pattern}\"", regex_patterns)))

        count_regex_statement = list(map(
            lambda field: f"count_matching_regex_{field} = countif({match_regex_statements(field, regex_patterns)}), count_not_empty_{field} = countif(isnotempty({field}))", fields))
        count_regex_statement = ", ".join(count_regex_statement)
        summarize_sum_statement = list(map(lambda field: f"Matching_{field} = sum(count_matching_regex_{field}), NotEmpty_{field} = sum(count_not_empty_{field})", fields))
        summarize_sum_statement = ", ".join(summarize_sum_statement)
        project_ratio_statement = list(map(lambda field: f"ratio_{field} = todouble(Matching_{field})/todouble(Matching_{field}+NotEmpty_{field})", fields))
        project_ratio_statement = ", ".join(project_ratio_statement)
        project_round_statement = list(map(lambda field: f"ratio_{field} = iff(isnan(ratio_{field}),0.0,round(ratio_{field}, 3))", fields))
        project_round_statement = ", ".join(project_round_statement)
        query = f"""
        StormEvents
        | where ingestion_time() > ago(1h)
        | summarize {count_regex_statement}
        | summarize {summarize_sum_statement}
        | project {project_ratio_statement}
        | project {project_round_statement}
        """
        clean_query = query.replace("\n", " ").strip()
        try:
            result = kusto_client.execute_query("Samples", clean_query)
        except Exception as err:
            logging.exception(
                f"Error while computing regex metric : {err}")
            result = []
        return result

## main.py

#provide your kusto client here
cluster = "https://help.kusto.windows.net" 
kcsb = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_interactive_login(cluster) 
client = KustoClient(kcsb)
fields = ["State"]
regex_patterns = ["[A-Z]*"]

metrics = match_regex_query(fields, regex_patterns, client)
```

Is there a better way to debug this problem?
TIA!

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: provided one in the post, should be easily replicable

Comment: Actually, here's a link to check how the queries are made for yourself, you'll see that they should work: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/3hE6FI9HunY

Comment: Works fine on my side (with some small changes). Please make your example fully reproducible. You can use the following code for authentication: ```cluster = "https://help.kusto.windows.net"
kcsb = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_interactive_login(cluster)
client = KustoClient(kcsb)```

Comment: you can run under a debugger and capture the actual query text before the query is invoked, to inspect its validity. if i had to guess, you have excessive commas (`,`s) in your `summarize` and `project` statements (e.g. after `count_not_empty_State=countif(isnotempty(State)),` and after `ratio_State=iff(isnan(ratio_State), 0.0, round(ratio_State, 3)),`. If so, removing these commas should fix your invalid syntax issue.

Comment: The commas you've seen earlier were due to typos when I copy/pasted and made the reproducible example, I've since fixed them.
I've also tried using the actual query text, and it seemed fine. You can check [here](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/A8Czcn7kpY8) a similar case where I have multiple fields, and no excessive commas.

Comment: I just checked the sending of the actual query (so no interpolation no nothing, just text), same result: parsing error via the SDK despite it working on Kusto Web UI. Is there a limit to the size of the queries I can send?

Comment: i would recommend you provide the client request ID of the query you run programmatically. if you don't explicitly set it - 1. you should; 2. you can find it using ".show queries", run against your cluster. without that, my other guess is that your regular expression strings include characters (e.g. `\\`) that need to be properly escaped

Comment: This is what I found via the query: `KPC.execute;ccf61db0-8026-4f43-99f8-1da8cdc431e1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the query your code generates is invalid, as the regular expressions include characters that aren't properly escaped.
see: [the string data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/string)

this is your invalid query (based on the client request ID you provided in the comments):

```
LiveStream_CL()
| where ingestion_time() > ago(1h)
| summarize count_matching_regex_deviceHostName_s = countif(deviceHostName_s matches regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9\$]([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.\$]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9\$])?$"), count_not_empty_deviceHostName_s = countif(isnotempty(deviceHostName_s)), count_matching_regex_sourceHostName_s = countif(sourceHostName_s matches regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9\$]([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.\$]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9\$])?$"), count_not_empty_sourceHostName_s = countif(isnotempty(sourceHostName_s)), count_matching_regex_destinationHostName_s = countif(destinationHostName_s matches regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9\$]([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.\$]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9\$])?$"), count_not_empty_destinationHostName_s = countif(isnotempty(destinationHostName_s)), count_matching_regex_agentHostName_s = countif(agentHostName_s matches regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9\$]([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.\$]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9\$])?$"), count_not_empty_agentHostName_s = countif(isnotempty(agentHostName_s))
...
```

whereas this is how it should look like (note the addition of the `@`s):

```
LiveStream_CL()
| where ingestion_time() > ago(1h)
| summarize
    count_matching_regex_deviceHostName_s = countif(deviceHostName_s matches regex @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\$]([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.\$]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9\$])?$"),
    count_not_empty_deviceHostName_s = countif(isnotempty(deviceHostName_s)),
    count_matching_regex_sourceHostName_s = countif(sourceHostName_s matches regex @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\$]([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.\$]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9\$])?$"),
    count_not_empty_sourceHostName_s = countif(isnotempty(sourceHostName_s)),
    count_matching_regex_destinationHostName_s = countif(destinationHostName_s matches regex @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\$]([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.\$]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9\$])?$"),
    count_not_empty_destinationHostName_s = countif(isnotempty(destinationHostName_s)),
    count_matching_regex_agentHostName_s = countif(agentHostName_s matches regex @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\$]([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.\$]{0, 61}[a-zA-Z0-9\$])?$"),
    count_not_empty_agentHostName_s = countif(isnotempty(agentHostName_s))
...
```

Comment: I see. Does the UI version apply automatically the `@` character before hand? Like in request `KustoWebV2;90e653b8-e0fc-4921-b013-505b8a966867` ? Because for the same query texts, both have different outcomes.

Comment: no, it does not. the query text for _that_ request you sent (as you can see on your own using ".show queries", look under the "Text" column) used backslash ("\") for escaping and not verbatim strings ("@"). those were probably added when you copied the text from your application, but they aren't added automatically by any ADX client (web UI or not), if you didn't include them in your input before running the query